# How make put ViewPager inside ScrollView and scroll all view as one part?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have an [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) that have [viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager) inside [scrollview](/questions/tagged/scrollview) like the follwoing

```
            <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!--someViews-->

                </LinearLayout>


                <!--then viewPager-->
                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Then the view pager holds some [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments) which have a tall view too.
The problem is the scroll view not scrolling because of the view is not need to scroll but the view inside the viewpager fragment's not scrolling
so, Is it possible to make the whole view including the inside view pager scroll as one view?
What I am saying that I don't need to scroll the viewpager fragment as separated part I need to scroll it as part of activity view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the setup you are looking for would work inside a CoordinatorLayout using the NestedScrollView widget like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/subtitle"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

      <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have just tested this with a sample project with a single text view in a Fragment and I was able to both scroll the view and swipe through the pages.

**Please note though**: I did have to *provide a specific height for the ViewPager* in order for it to display.

Comment: yes it worked when I put a high to the viewpager but I don't need to do that because I don't know what high will be enough for the fragment inside  the  viewpager

Comment: @Tefa if that is the case, then ViewPager is not the right widget to use. Consider using a RecyclerView with a horizontal LayoutManager, the NestedScrollView would still apply though.

Comment: I already removed the recycler-view and used FrameLayout and replaced may fragments on it

Comment: This is working well but why we have to use fixed height ? Because hard code isn't recommended. Is there any other way ? Thanks.

Comment: @MehmetGür i believe NestedScrollView wraps it's content, so despite saying match parent in the layout it doesn't know how big to draw itself so the child needs to be sized instead